# Java how to automatically output last line?

Tags: java, parsing, system.out

I am currently working on an assignment where I have to be able to read a certain predetermined amount of lines of input, each of which correlate to a certain line of output. Simply put, if I have 200 lines of input, I should also have 200 lines of output. I read the input through a scanner on the standard input, copy pasting it into the standard input, and every line, except the last line, is automatically outputted. For the last line to appear, I have to press enter. How do I make it so that this last line automatically appears and I don't have to press enter?

```
    int numberOfPackets = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPackets; i++){

        String nextLine = in.nextLine();

        if (nextLine.charAt(0) == 'D'){                             //Check to see if the packet is a data packet or a router packet
            out.print("\n" + dataParser(nextLine));
        } else if (nextLine.charAt(0) == 'R'){
            out.print("\n" + routeParser(nextLine));
        }
    }
```

This is the code that reads each line into input, is there something I'm missing?

Edit: I cannot edit the input to include an empty line at the end as many of you have suggested. This is a brilliant solution but unfortunately I'm not allowed to do this!

Comment: Could you provide a sample file content (10 lines for instance), and what kind of object is `out`  ?

Comment: Seems like your problem is in pasting values in standard input. When you copying from your source it must be carriage return (CR,LF) symbol(s) in all lines except last. You can enable special characters in some text editor like Notepad++ and check.

Comment: Where are you reading from? Is it from a file or from the console?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the documentation of `Scanner.nextLine()`,

> **Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a line separator**, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line to skip if no line separators are present.

Since you are copying and pasting the lines to the standard input, you need to have the line separator `\n` on the end of the last line for `nextLine()` to work. When you hit enter, `\n` is added to the end of the last line, which is why the last line will print - the Scanner detects it and finishes reading the line.

Remember that `\n` is not actually visible, but marks the end of a line.

You can fix this by placing an empty line at the end of your pasted input.

Comment: If reading from a file, you shouldn't need an empty line at the end. Even if the last line does not end with `\n` (or any other terminator), Scanner will still treat it as a line. Maybe the problem is that the OP is typing in the input, and hasn't hit Enter on the last line, so Scanner doesn't realise the line has ended.

Comment: @Dewick47, you read the question inattentively, the author mentions that all the lines printed except the last.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException "Maybe the problem is that the OP is typing in the input, and hasn't hit Enter on the last line, so Scanner doesn't realise the line has ended." This is exactly the problem, I assume that when I paste the input into the console, the scanner is 'waiting' for me to finish writing the last line, as if there could be more input, but I want it to just read this last line given as it is and output the corresponding line.

Comment: @SergeyProkofiev Where did I say the opposite? Were you looking at my pre-edit version with the information about the file? The "When you hit enter" part of my answer is referring to why the last line DOES print when he finally hits enter. Otherwise, I think I'm missing what you mean.

Comment: @Chuckster Then the end of line characters the Scanner is expecting have to be added in some shape or form. You'll need to hit enter or paste it with an empty line.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue caused by the method of how you're copying-pasting your data to standard input. For instance if you have 3 lines in your source file like this.

[image]

I can easily reproduce your behavior with simple code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

When you're selecting lines all lines except last will have CRLF symbols, so scanner treat it as end of input and you saw your output.

You can open your source file, move cursor to the last character and press "Enter" and try your test again. I think it would work as you expect.

Hope it helps!